# How determine if using SSL in a MySql Connection?

Tags: c#, mysql, ssl, database-connection, wireshark

We are using v6.9.9 of the .Net MySql Connector to access MySql using this connection string, specifying that SSL is required.

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
SSL Mode=Required
```

Our DBA has turned on support for SSL, but during my testing, I am able to connect to the server regardless of whether I have certificates installed on my machine, and also regardless of whether I have "SSL Mode=Required" or not.

However, when my DBA disabled SSL, if I use the above connection string, I got an error that SSL was not enabled.

Therefore, I really just don't know if my network traffic is being encrypted or not. How can I verify?

--

My question is a bit of a duplicate to this one with no accepted answer.

[How to check whether a MySQL connection is SSL encrypted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389921/how-to-check-whether-a-mysql-connection-is-ssl-encrypted)

Some recommend using WireShark to test. Does anyone have step-by-step instructions on how to use this tool to verify my SSL connections?

--

This link talks about calling "status" from the MySql client.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36776/how-can-i-verify-im-using-ssl-to-connect-to-mysql

I asked my DBA to try it - but he isn't able to call that method against my connection, only against his local connection. Is there anyway to call this, for example, within my c# code?
I tried this, but I don't think the returned values tell me if the connection is SSL or not.

```
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE '%Ssl%';
```

Anyone with detailed information on how to verify my SSL connections would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work a lot with databases, but network/wireshark expertise is enough for you task. So what should you do:

1. Prepare capture setup using [this tutorial](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup)
2. Start sniffing network with wireshark and perform some queries to your database
3. Filter traffic by database IP-address and/or port using [display filter](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters), so irrelevant packets aren't shown
4. Examine displayed packets. Compare them to [sample of MySQL over TCP](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures#MySQL_protocol) and to [sample of MySQL over SSL](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures#SSL_with_decryption_keys). Hint: you can see queries as a plain text in unprotected connection, while SSL makes packet payload look like bunch of random garbage.