# Connect to MySQL using SSL in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, ssl

I'm connecting to a MySQL server that requires SSL, using a `MySqlConnection`:

```
var connection = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=127.0.0.1;Database=MyDb1;User Id=root;Password=blabla;encrypt=true");
```

This succeeds if the server doesn't require SSL, but after executing `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' REQUIRE SSL;` on the server, it starts failing with:

> ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Authentication to host '127.0.0.1' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

How is SSL enabled? Should something be added to the connection string or is it done programmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, after some more searching I found the answer at [How determine if using SSL in a MySql Connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703027/how-determine-if-using-ssl-in-a-mysql-connection).

I had to add `SSL Mode=Required` instead of `encrypt=true` to the connection string:

```
var connection = new MySqlConnection("SSL Mode=Required;Data Source=127.0.0.1;Database=MyDb1;User Id=root;Password=blabla");
```

Now I'm getting a new error - [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: “The host localhost does not support SSL connections.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086283/mysql-data-mysqlclient-mysqlexception-the-host-localhost-does-not-support-ssl), but I think I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This connecting string work for me with `MySQL Comunity Server 8.0.35`.

1. Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77366534/problem-with-in-house-generated-certificate-in-mysql/77464850#77464850) to generate SLL Certificates for `MySQL Server (*.pem)` and for `C# Client (client.pfx)`
2. I use connString like this:

> ```
> String connString = "server=localhost;
>                      user id=root;
>                      database=YOUR_DB_NAME;
>                      persistsecurityinfo=True;
>                      password=YOUR_DB_PASSWORD;
>                      allowuservariables=True;
>                      allowbatch=True;
>                      sslmode=Required;
>                      certificatepassword=YOUR_PFX_CERTIFICATE_PASS;
>                      certificatefile=YOUR_PFX_CERTIFICATE_FILE;"
> ```

Example

```
 YOUR_DB_NAME = discount_card
 YOUR_DB_PASSWORD = db_p455w0rd
 YOUR_PFX_CERTIFICATE_PASS = pfx_p455w0rd
 YOUR_PFX_CERTIFICATE_FILE = D:\\certificates\\client.pfx
```

Answer (score -2):

var connection = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=127.0.0.1;Database=MyDb1;User Id=root;Password=blabla;SSL Mode=None");

For me Working Fine...

Comment: For anyone looking for an answer to this question, this is not it. As you can see, the question is how to use SSL, not how to disable it.

Comment: Scary how this is positioned at the top, when it simply ignores SSL

Answer (score -2):

You can use this in your connection string.

```
 SSL Mode=0
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try with another user like 'User1@%' or 'User1@192.168.x.x'
I hope that can help you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).