# Problem with "in house" generated certificate in mysql

Tags: mysql, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to configure my (Docker) mysql instance (v8.1.0) to use my "in house" generated certificate. So far I've been unable to get it to work. MySQL throws an SSL/TLS exception during startup.

I have two files:

```
certificate_name.cer
certificate_name.key
```

and I have the following in my conf file:

```
ssl_cert=/certs/certificate_name.cer
ssl_key=/certs/certificate_name.key
require_secure_transport=ON
```

"/certs" is my name bound volume mount in Docker.

When I start my Dockerized mysql instance I get the following error:

```
2023-10-26T10:57:22.239715Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013595] [Server] Failed to initialize TLS for channel: mysql_main. See below for the description of exact issue.

2023-10-26T10:57:22.239734Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010069] [Server] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed

2023-10-26T10:57:22.275267Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011302] [Server] Plugin mysqlx reported: 'Failed at SSL configuration: "SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key"'
```

I haven't specified the `ssl_ca` setting as I don't know what to set it to. Is there a setting to ignore verifying the ca?

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I was creating `SSL certificates` for `MySQL Server 8.0.35` with `C# Client`. And alhamdulillah I managed to do it. Hope it's useful for others.

Steps on how to do it.

1. Create `D://Certificates` folder.
2. Create 4 files (`MySqlCerts.bat`, `ca.cnf`, `server.cnf`, `client.cnf`) in `D://Certificates` folder.
3. Copy `each scripts` to `4 files`, and don't mix them up.
4. Change `YOUR_PASSWORD`,`C`, `ST`, `L`, `O`, `OU` in `scripts` according to your wishes.
5. Run `MySqlCerts.bat` as `Administrator`, then you will get the following certificates:

- `ca-cert.pem` (CA Certificate)
- `ca-key.pem` (CA PrivateKey)
- `server-cert.pem` (Server Certificate)
- `server-key.pem` (Server PrivateKey)
- `server-req.pem` (Remove Server PassPhrase)
- `client-cert.pem` (Client Certificate)
- `client-key.pem` (Client PrivateKey)
- `client-req.pem` (Remove Client PassPhrase)
- `client.pfx` (Use with the .NET client because .NET doesn't support pem format)

6. Edit config in `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini` as follows:

> ```
> [client]
> ssl-ca=D:/Certificates/ca-cert.pem
> ssl-cert=D:/Certificates/client-cert.pem
> ssl-key=D:/Certificates/client-key.pem
>
> [mysqld]
> ssl-ca=D:/Certificates/ca-cert.pem
> ssl-cert=D:/Certificates/server-cert.pem
> ssl-key=D:/Certificates/server-key.pem
> require_secure_transport=ON
> ```

7. Open `MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client` in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0` then typo

   `mysql> restart;`

   Wait for 5 seconds then typo:

   `mysql> status;`

   You will get as follows if SSL is worked on MySql Server.

   `SSL: Cipher in use is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`

Details:

> ```
> --------------
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe  Ver 8.0.35 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
>
> Connection id:          8
> Current database:
> Current user:           root@localhost
> SSL:                    Cipher in use is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> Using delimiter:        ;
> Server version:         8.0.35 MySQL Community Server - GPL
> Protocol version:       10
> Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
> Server characterset:    utf8mb4
> Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
> Client characterset:    cp850
> Conn.  characterset:    cp850
> TCP port:               3306
> Binary data as:         Hexadecimal
> Uptime:                 9 sec
>
> Threads: 2  Questions: 4  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 119  Flush tables: 3  Open tables: 38  Queries per second avg: 0.444
> --------------
> ```

Or you can look in the `Error log` of `MySql Server`, if `SSL is successfully configured` it will look like this:

```
2023-11-11T11:26:22.003199Z 8 [System] [MY-011086] [Server] Received RESTART from user root.  Restarting mysqld (Version: 8.0.35).
2023-11-11T11:26:25.375010Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2023-11-11T11:26:26.384849Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.35) starting as process 18908
2023-11-11T11:26:26.452467Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-11-11T11:26:30.279926Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-11-11T11:26:32.243365Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate D:/Certificates/ca-cert.pem is self signed.
2023-11-11T11:26:32.244622Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-11-11T11:26:32.425990Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2023-11-11T11:26:32.426129Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.35'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

8. Test SSL connection with `cmd prompt`.

   If no error appears (display as below) after entering the password,
   then the SSL connection from the client to the MySQL server has been
   successful.

> ```
> C:\Windows\System32>mysql -h localhost -u root -p --ssl-ca=D:/Certificates/ca-cert.pem --ssl-cert=D:/Certificates/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=D:/Certificates/client-key.pem
> Enter password: ******
> Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
> Your MySQL connection id is 16
> Server version: 8.0.35 MySQL Community Server - GPL
>
> Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
>
> Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
> affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
> owners.
>
> Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
> ```

**Scripts:**

MySqlCerts.bat

```
@ECHO OFF

c:
cd c:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\

echo.
echo #OpenSSL version
openssl version



echo.
echo Create CA PrivateKey (ca-key.pem)
openssl genrsa 2048 > D:\Certificates\ca-key.pem

echo.
echo Create CA Certificate (ca-cert.pem)
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 36500 -key D:\Certificates\ca-key.pem -config D:\Certificates\ca.cnf > D:\Certificates\ca-cert.pem



echo.
echo Create Server PrivateKey (server-key.pem)
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout D:\Certificates\server-key.pem -config D:\Certificates\server.cnf > D:\Certificates\server-req.pem

echo.
echo Remove PassPhrase(server-req.pem)
openssl rsa -in D:\Certificates\server-key.pem -out D:\Certificates\server-key.pem

echo.
echo Create Server Certificate (server-cert.pem)
openssl x509 -req -in D:\Certificates\server-req.pem -days 36500 -CA D:\Certificates\ca-cert.pem -CAkey D:\Certificates\ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 > D:\Certificates\server-cert.pem



echo.
echo Create Client PrivateKey (client-key.pem)
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout D:\Certificates\client-key.pem -config D:\Certificates\client.cnf > D:\Certificates\client-req.pem

echo.
echo Remove PassPhrase (client-req.pem)
openssl rsa -in D:\Certificates\client-key.pem -out D:\Certificates\client-key.pem

echo.
echo Create Client Certificate (client-cert.pem)
openssl x509 -req -in D:\Certificates\client-req.pem -days 36500 -CA D:\Certificates\ca-cert.pem -CAkey D:\Certificates\ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 > D:\Certificates\client-cert.pem


echo.
echo Create Client Certificate (client.pfx for C#)
openssl pkcs12 -export -in D:\Certificates\client-cert.pem -inkey D:\Certificates\client-key.pem -certfile D:\Certificates\ca-cert.pem -password pass:YOUR_PASSWORD -out D:\Certificates\client.pfx

pause
```

ca.cnf

```
[req]
distinguished_name=distinguished_name
prompt=no
[distinguished_name]
C=ID
ST=Jawa Timur
L=Ngawi
O=Ctech
OU=Software Engineer
CN=CtechCA
emailAddress=youremail@hotmail.com
```

server.cnf

```
[req]
distinguished_name=distinguished_name
attributes=attributes
prompt=no
[distinguished_name]
C=ID
ST=Jawa Timur
L=Ngawi
O=Ctech
OU=Software Engineer
CN=localhost
emailAddress=youremail@hotmail.com
[attributes]
challengePassword=YOUR_PASSWORD
```

client.cnf

```
[req]
distinguished_name=distinguished_name
attributes=attributes
prompt=no
[distinguished_name]
C=ID
ST=Jawa Timur
L=Ngawi
O=Ctech
OU=Software Engineer
CN=localhost
emailAddress=youremail@hotmail.com
[attributes]
challengePassword=YOUR_PASSWORD
```

Look at [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html) as references.